# How to set when user first open the website it open the special URL of the site?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have a simple nuxt.js project:

this is the struct of the pages.
you see:

```
about_us
contact_us
image
search
index.vue
```

when I open the site `http://localhost:3000/`, of course it open `index.vue` by default, but I want it open the `http://localhost:3000/search`.

how to set this?

I tried change `@/pages/_lang/index.vue` to `@/pages/_lang/search/index.vue` in `pages/index.vue`:

```
<script>
  import Index from '@/pages/_lang/search/index.vue'   # I change there.
  export default Index
</script>
```

it will open `http://localhost:3000/` with `/search/index.vue`, but I can not enter `index.vue` any more.

---

I mean, I want to open `http://localhost:3000/` first time it will jump to `http://localhost:3000/search`, but the next time open it by click navigate bar `home` button, it will be `http://localhost:3000/` don't jump.

[image]

Comment: So, everytime the users types the URL that ends with a `/` path, he will be redirected to `/search`, but if you have some client side navigation with your navbar, you want him to go to the usual `/` path. Did I understood this one properly?

Comment: you understand right.

Comment: you could put your search page in index.vue and the home page to home.vue, this way you can achieve both of your requirements